# How to install opening to the side in the ui shape?

Tags: jquery, css, semantic-ui

Amoclan shape makes switching to the next side. To me it is necessary that the transition proishodit appointed me to the side. I tried to implement it as written in the documentation, but transition is still going on to the next side.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="static/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/semantic.min.css">
    <script src="static/semantic.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="ui shape">
      <div class="sides">
        <div class="side active">This side starts visible 1</div>
        <div class="side two">This is yet another side 2</div>
        <div class="side three">This is yet another side 3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>

    <div id="move">move</div>

    <script>
        $('#move').click(function(){
            $('.shape').shape('.three', '.second.side').shape('flip left')
        })
    </script>
</body>
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: can you point me to the link where you are seeing this?

Comment: @SahilDhir 
Its here http://semantic-ui.com/modules/shape.html#/usage

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the working example of your code as you wanted.**  There was a small mistake which I have fixed. I hope this is what you wanted.

```js
$('#move').on('click', function(){ 
            $('.shape').shape('.three', '.second.side').shape('flip left')
        })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://semantic-ui.com/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://semantic-ui.com/dist/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="ui shape">
      <div class="sides">
        <div class="side active">This side starts visible 1</div>
        <div class="side two">This is yet another side 2</div>
        <div class="side three">This is yet another side 3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>

    <div id="move">move</div>
```

Comment: I don't see that your code was different from mine.
When first clicked, I'd like to see a side of 3 and not 2...